# ProLiant DL360p Gen8 Install

Tags: networking, server, hp

Apologies for any newbie first post errors...
I recently bought an old server (HPE ProLiant DL360p G8) to setup a home lab. I've tried to install numerous OSs but cannot get network cards working. I've updated iLo and BIOS to latest using SPP software from HP. I have successfully installed Ubuntu Server 18.04.6 and it runs well - except I have no network that the Ubuntu installation can access. The iLo4 system has an IP address and I can access the iLo drive from a networked computer. Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions.

I am getting the following error messages repetitively and I think it's related.
[hid-generic error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5yh3.png)

Thanks for your quick replies matigo and chili555.

And here is output for lshw
[lshw1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5yh3.png)

Sorry for the images. Thanks again for the help.

The iLO is software that let's you manage the [server remotely](https://www.hpe.com/us/en/servers/integrated-lights-out-ilo.html). I believe that it is installed on an internal SD card. It has it's own separate IP address and ethernet card from the rest of the machine. I'd never heard of it before, but then I've never worked with an HPE server before either.

I did try to set a static IP as you can see, but that failed too. Here's the yaml files in /etc/netplan: [yaml printout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC3FC.jpg)

Here's the latest update chilli555. I appreciate your patience.
[netplan-and-ipaddr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni4Lt.png)

So I updated the yaml file using the sample [static.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8D3t.png), then generated and applied. I now have an [ip address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmx0s.png). However, still no internet access. Thanks for your help chilli555. I'll start a new investigation as to the internet thing. Thanks again!

Here's results of [ping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW2TT.png).

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the terminal output of: (0) `sudo lshw -c network` (1) `sudo lspci`? This will show specific information about your hardware, which may help with finding a solution 

Comment: The error message relates to *hid-generic.* HID  devices today include a broad range of devices such as alphanumeric displays, bar code readers, volume controls on speakers/headsets, auxiliary displays, sensors and many others. It is not related to ethernet devices.

Comment: So far, so good! Next may we see: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` "The iLo4 system has an IP address" Please explain/elaborate.  Thanks.

Comment: I wonder why you have two apparently conflicting yaml files. I suggest that you rename one: `sudo mv /etc/netplan/99_config.yaml  /etc/netplan/99_config.bak` Now do: `sudo netplan generate` and then: `sudo netplan apply` Please show us any errors, warnings, etc. If none, let us see: `ip addr show` and: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8`

Comment: Please see: `cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/dhcp.yaml` Your file seems to lack: `renderer: networkd` Please add it to your file with the correct indentation and try again: `sudo netplan generate` then:`sudo netplan apply` and finally: `ip addr show` No need to show us the result unless there is an error or warning. Did one of the interfaces, eno1 perhaps, get a valid IP address?

Comment: "However, still no internet access." Can you ping the gateway? How about: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` ?

Comment: Are you quite sure that 10.10.2.xx is the correct address range? How do you know that, of the four ethernet ports, that eno1 is where the cable is connected?

Comment: So. Thanks so much for your help chili555. I have moved the server and placed it on a second network. BOOM! Got an IP address no problem. Obviously it's got to do with settings for DHCP. Rookie mistake. Your time and patience are much appreciated.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working by whatever means. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

The DL360 has no network ports by default.

You need a FlexLOM board with either RJ45,SFP+ or QSFP plugged in (or an PCIe NIC)

Never in a million years will the ILO hole talk to the OS.

If you did a default Ubuntu install you will have any internal nics set you DHCP4 enabled

IP A will hive a list of what the OS can see..

Note the naming, you /etc/netplan/*.yaml file MUST use the same naming!!!

I think you have your cable in the wrong hole TBH!